# Objective-C (cocoa) equivalent to python's endswith/beginswith

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa

Python has `string.startswith()` and `string.endswith()` functions which are pretty useful.
What NSString methods can I use to have the same function?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use [`-hasPrefix:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasPrefix%3a) and [`-hasSuffix:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasSuffix%3a):

```
NSString *s = @"foobar";
NSLog(@"%d %d\n", [s hasPrefix:@"foo"], [s hasSuffix:@"bar"]);
// Output: "1 1"
```

Answer (score 8):

You want the [`hasPrefix`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasPrefix%3a) and [`hasSuffix`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasSuffix%3a) messages.

I tend to also use the [`compare:options:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare%3aoptions%3a) message pretty regularly to achieve the same but with case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 5):

-hasPrefix() and -hasSuffix() return YES or NO depending on whether the receiver begins or ends with the given substring. If that's what startswith() and endswith() do, then that's your answer.